# What are some fullnode health indicators in geth? (mgasps etc.)

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I run a few ETH fullnodes using the Geth implementation, and I'm curious about some of the metrics, specifically `mgas`, `mgasps` and how they reflect the health state of the node.

Here is the output of one of my nodes running on an HDD (no 500GB+ SSD available on this server):

```
ethereumd           | INFO [10-04|20:50:30.998] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=220285 size=63.70mB time=2.621488822s gcnodes=329050 gcsize=139.56mB gctime=1.202094642s livenodes=190333 livesize=71.27mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-04|20:50:31.164] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=72  mgas=7.997  elapsed=12.535s   mgasps=0.638 number=6453859 hash=168064…2879b1 age=21m42s   cache=83.45mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-04|20:50:54.121] Imported new chain segment               blocks=2 txs=154 mgas=8.512  elapsed=22.957s   mgasps=0.371 number=6453861 hash=2ba650…447478 age=21m35s   cache=84.37mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-04|20:51:19.445] Imported new chain segment               blocks=2 txs=143 mgas=15.987 elapsed=25.323s   mgasps=0.631 number=6453863 hash=dc69a9…58ee06 age=21m35s   cache=84.83mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-04|20:51:42.808] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=134 mgas=7.968  elapsed=23.363s   mgasps=0.341 number=6453864 hash=4d49d0…8f701e age=21m53s   cache=85.28mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-04|20:52:13.794] Imported new chain segment               blocks=2 txs=140 mgas=9.738  elapsed=30.986s   mgasps=0.314 number=6453866 hash=a05129…9ce4e8 age=21m25s   cache=86.16mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-04|20:52:36.808] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=122 mgas=7.993  elapsed=23.014s   mgasps=0.347 number=6453867 hash=5e854d…6dc887 age=21m45s   cache=86.89mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-04|20:52:53.310] Imported new chain segment               blocks=2 txs=99  mgas=8.135  elapsed=16.501s   mgasps=0.493 number=6453869 hash=c7612c…9e3d36 age=21m30s   cache=87.20mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-04|20:53:23.095] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=139 mgas=7.985  elapsed=29.784s   mgasps=0.268 number=6453870 hash=5dfe3a…6f6858 age=21m56s   cache=88.04mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-04|20:53:37.701] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=86  mgas=4.222  elapsed=14.606s   mgasps=0.289 number=6453871 hash=c45b82…f70537 age=22m7s    cache=88.30mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-04|20:53:55.856] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=122 mgas=7.998  elapsed=18.154s   mgasps=0.441 number=6453872 hash=e3a4ca…2f0ced age=21m9s    cache=89.16mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-04|20:54:22.650] Imported new chain segment               blocks=2 txs=217 mgas=10.376 elapsed=26.793s   mgasps=0.387 number=6453874 hash=d29f57…32ad38 age=20m57s   cache=90.09mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-04|20:54:34.161] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=121 mgas=7.992  elapsed=11.510s   mgasps=0.694 number=6453875 hash=a524a1…2cac5c age=21m8s    cache=90.55mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-04|20:54:44.728] Imported new chain segment               blocks=2 txs=111 mgas=8.023  elapsed=10.567s   mgasps=0.759 number=6453877 hash=8f7233…6d2922 age=21m15s   cache=90.73mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-04|20:54:54.542] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=148 mgas=7.936  elapsed=9.813s    mgasps=0.809 number=6453878 hash=703fbc…ee9d8c age=21m8s    cache=91.35mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-04|20:55:07.218] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=34  mgas=7.694  elapsed=12.675s   mgasps=0.607 number=6453879 hash=db34c4…5dd7c8 age=21m15s   cache=91.78mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-04|20:55:21.847] Imported new chain segment               blocks=4 txs=165 mgas=15.702 elapsed=14.629s   mgasps=1.073 number=6453883 hash=9928e7…9d7f76 age=20m48s   cache=91.87mB
```

Compared to similar logs from another server with SSD and cache set to 32GB RAM:

```
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|17:59:03.111] Imported new chain segment               blocks=128 txs=11416 mgas=534.753 elapsed=8.026s    mgasps=66.626 number=4144918 hash=add838…34d9c7 age=1y2mo2h  cache=357.69mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|17:59:10.613] Imported new chain segment               blocks=96  txs=10755 mgas=492.841 elapsed=7.501s    mgasps=65.700 number=4145014 hash=e88c65…12a7f7 age=1y2mo1h  cache=361.24mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|17:59:18.705] Imported new chain segment               blocks=75  txs=8813  mgas=373.340 elapsed=8.008s    mgasps=46.621 number=4145089 hash=12c34f…33bb17 age=1y2mo1h  cache=371.60mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|17:59:26.727] Imported new chain segment               blocks=116 txs=10780 mgas=521.399 elapsed=8.021s    mgasps=65.001 number=4145205 hash=1093f7…84f560 age=1y2mo30m cache=366.14mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|17:59:34.820] Imported new chain segment               blocks=102 txs=10523 mgas=535.874 elapsed=8.093s    mgasps=66.212 number=4145307 hash=4758f3…4ebfdf age=1y1mo4w  cache=373.14mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|17:59:42.883] Imported new chain segment               blocks=108 txs=9047  mgas=532.010 elapsed=8.062s    mgasps=65.982 number=4145415 hash=38773e…c829f0 age=1y1mo4w  cache=371.01mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|17:59:51.090] Imported new chain segment               blocks=107 txs=10426 mgas=523.974 elapsed=8.206s    mgasps=63.847 number=4145522 hash=7e0af6…4dae2d age=1y1mo4w  cache=374.76mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|17:59:59.151] Imported new chain segment               blocks=137 txs=10877 mgas=482.137 elapsed=8.060s    mgasps=59.811 number=4145659 hash=41976e…64317a age=1y1mo4w  cache=371.01mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|18:00:07.168] Imported new chain segment               blocks=117 txs=9329  mgas=519.324 elapsed=8.017s    mgasps=64.776 number=4145776 hash=00f743…3b61bf age=1y1mo4w  cache=375.24mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|18:00:15.216] Imported new chain segment               blocks=138 txs=10790 mgas=550.327 elapsed=8.048s    mgasps=68.376 number=4145914 hash=0f424c…d1dfdf age=1y1mo4w  cache=374.70mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|18:00:23.240] Imported new chain segment               blocks=116 txs=10498 mgas=523.948 elapsed=8.023s    mgasps=65.299 number=4146030 hash=e590d5…9ea114 age=1y1mo4w  cache=383.84mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|18:00:31.293] Imported new chain segment               blocks=173 txs=10638 mgas=517.174 elapsed=8.053s    mgasps=64.219 number=4146203 hash=c1b64d…ad92d5 age=1y1mo4w  cache=372.28mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|18:00:39.356] Imported new chain segment               blocks=121 txs=10188 mgas=491.866 elapsed=8.062s    mgasps=61.004 number=4146324 hash=645e54…c76ecd age=1y1mo4w  cache=388.10mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|18:00:47.367] Imported new chain segment               blocks=133 txs=10995 mgas=537.147 elapsed=8.011s    mgasps=67.051 number=4146457 hash=5cde5f…ba3afb age=1y1mo4w  cache=390.97mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|18:00:55.437] Imported new chain segment               blocks=148 txs=10775 mgas=478.164 elapsed=8.069s    mgasps=59.257 number=4146605 hash=77a429…1dbbbd age=1y1mo4w  cache=386.82mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|18:01:03.472] Imported new chain segment               blocks=149 txs=11363 mgas=502.537 elapsed=8.035s    mgasps=62.540 number=4146754 hash=eb68a1…8f8e2e age=1y1mo4w  cache=392.12mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|18:01:11.621] Imported new chain segment               blocks=92  txs=14986 mgas=486.517 elapsed=8.148s    mgasps=59.706 number=4146846 hash=28353e…d269b7 age=1y1mo4w  cache=413.62mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|18:01:19.631] Imported new chain segment               blocks=89  txs=14916 mgas=508.928 elapsed=8.010s    mgasps=63.534 number=4146935 hash=2ea3e7…271bd6 age=1y1mo4w  cache=423.72mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|18:01:27.696] Imported new chain segment               blocks=81  txs=12951 mgas=434.866 elapsed=8.065s    mgasps=53.918 number=4147016 hash=69dbd7…47e5fd age=1y1mo4w  cache=423.46mB
ethereumd           | INFO [10-05|18:01:31.396] Imported new chain segment               blocks=46  txs=5275  mgas=208.641 elapsed=3.699s    mgasps=56.392 number=4147062 hash=c26b17…12aad5 age=1y1mo4w  cache=421.77mB
```

The block dates are much different since the SSD server is still catching up, but immediately I notice that `mgasps` is much higher and `elapsed` block sync times are consistently lower.

Could someone explain the significance of these and possibly some tweaks to improve the health and sync-time of my nodes?